# To create restful api for android team in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, rest

I am currently creating Rest API for Android Team using Laravel 5.2 and testing the API in RESTCLIENT.

I am just trying to get the form values which are entered in Restclient with POST method.

I have problem with POST method.. I m just not able to get the form field values. My API for GET method works fine.

Kindly guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Show your controller function how you handle post method

Comment: public function test()
    {
     $name = Request::input('name');
     echo $name;
    }

Comment: and this gives you what error when you echo `$name`?

Comment: @EddyTheDove.... I just wanna get the form values. I have even disabled the verfifycsrfToken. Though I have no issues with the GET method.

Comment: I do not get any error.. It just does not display the entered value.

Comment: I have even tried with fresh laravel instance

Comment: Check my solution below and see how it goes. Else, yep, you can try with a fresh install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you handle POST request in laravel. Be it 5.2 or 5.4.

```
Route::post('books', 'BookController@store');
```

Controller

```
pubic function store(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->name;
    $name = $request->get('name');
    $name = request('name'); //global helper 

    //Your testing with api so you should return to api if you want to see it
    return response()->json($name);
}
```

Then check in Android console if you receive `$name`  in JSON format.

Comment: I have tried all these Eddy.. Still I did not get the value.. I tried to send the json response also

Comment: I have created REST Apis in Laravel 4.2. But I did not face any such issues

Comment: In your android console, do you see your data being POSTed?

Comment: No.. I dont work in Android. We just write APIs for the android team to inegrate. The one way to test our APIs is using Restclient or Postman

Comment: Perfect, you did with Potman and it didnt work? That would be a miracle. No error. No response. No nothing. Are those routes in the `web` middleware?

Comment: Trust me... I m struggling with this for past 2 days.

Comment: Please, try a fresh install on the side and just try the same thing again. Because GET works but not POST. It should be a route problem or csfr token issue

Comment: Thanks Eddy... I m getting the form details with $name = request('name'); and I have no idea why others dont work.

Comment: Oh good. I have no idea. `request()` is just a global helper. Well, if this helps your answer, please don't forget to mark the answer. Thanks :)